# Couchbase - updating object inside a document

Tags: couchbase, sql++

If I have the following document for example:
{
“make”:“BMW”,
“make1”:“AUDI”
}

When I do an UPDATE query UPDATE Translations SET `make2` = “MERCEDES” WHERE META().id = “CARS” , there is no problem with the query and make2 is added to the document.

When I do an UPDATE query UPDATE Translations SET `make2`.`MODEL` = “CLS”, `make2`.`MODIFICATION` = “500” WHERE META().id = "CARS"
The query returns “sucess”, but nothing is added. If make2 already exists everything is updated as expected, the problem only appears if the object does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only update the nested properties if the parent property is a JSON Object. If the parent property is set to a string, the update will not succeed, contrary to what you stated.

This will work:

```
UPDATE Translations USE KEYS "CARS" 
    SET make2 = {};
UPDATE Translations USE KEYS "CARS" 
    SET make2.MODEL = "CLS", d.make7.MODIFICATION = "500";
```

Or you can do this in one line:

```
UPDATE Translations USE KEYS "CARS" 
    SET make2 = {}, make2.MODEL = "CLS", d.make7.MODIFICATION = "500";
```

Comment: I was giving an example with a common string property, not a nested property with parent set to string, and the second example succeeded if make2 already existed as an object. I tried your suggestion and set make2 = {} and now it works, thanks.

Comment: But you have to be careful! Everything else in make2 will be deleted, so you are technically not setting the path but replacing the object make2 with {MODEL: "CLS"}. You will loose everything else that was in make2 before. See https://forums.couchbase.com/t/updating-an-entity-object-problem/14778/2 where someone postet a better solution preserving make2's content and updating just MODEL.